# Check if an object has keys that are in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to get the list of non existent or existent keys in an object depending on an array of keys.

What I'm able to do is to verify for the moment if it exists or not, but I want to know which key does or doesn't exist.

```js
const obj = {Password: '123456', Username: 'MeMyselfAndI'}
const checkFields= ['Method', 'Password', 'Username','email']
const result = checkFields.every(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key));
console.log(result); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code helping you

```
checkFields.filter(o=>!(Object.keys(obj)).includes(o))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a partition for having the keys separated in a single object:

```js
const obj = {Password: '123456', Username: 'MeMyselfAndI'}
const checkFields = ['Method', 'Password', 'Username', 'email']



const createFieldPartition = (ob, fields) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(ob);
  return fields.reduce( (acc, cur) => {
    if (keys.includes(cur) ) { acc.existing.push(cur); }
    else { acc.notExisting.push(cur); }
    return acc
  }, {existing:[], notExisting:[]} );
}


console.log(createFieldPartition(obj, checkFields))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {Password: '123456', Username: 'MeMyselfAndI'}
const checkFields= ['Method', 'Password', 'Username','email'];

let existing_fields = [];
let unexisting_fields =  [];

checkFields.map(field => {
  if(Object.keys(obj).indexOf(field) != -1) {
      existing_fields.push(field);
  } else {
    unexisting_fields.push(field);
  }
});

console.log("Unexisting fields", unexisting_fields);
console.log("Eexisting fields", existing_fields);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator to check if object contains a key.

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.

```js
const obj = {Password: '123456', Username: 'MeMyselfAndI'}
const checkFields= ['Method', 'Password', 'Username','email']
const result = checkFields.filter(key => key in obj);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop over the array and create an object where the properties are set to either `true` or `false`.

```js
const obj = {Password: '123456', Username: 'MeMyselfAndI'};
const checkFields= ['Method', 'Password', 'Username','email'];

const result = { 'true': [], 'false': [] };

for (let el of checkFields) {
  const value = obj[el] ? true : false;
  result[value].push(el);
}

console.log(`Exists: ${result.true.join(' ')}`);
console.log(`Do not exist: ${result.false.join(' ')}`);
```